# Could not make a CTParagraphStyleRef on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I found a strange problem when using the CoreText. Below is the code:

```
CGFloat headindent = theme.horizontalMargin.floatValue; // 10.0
CTParagraphStyleSetting head;
head.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierHeadIndent;
head.value = &headindent;
head.valueSize = sizeof(float);


CGFloat tailindent = -theme.horizontalMargin.floatValue; //-10.0
CTParagraphStyleSetting tail;
tail.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierTailIndent;
tail.value = &tailindent;
tail.valueSize = sizeof(float);


CGFloat firstlineindent =theme.horizontalMargin.floatValue;//10.0
CTParagraphStyleSetting firstline;
firstline.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent;
firstline.value = &firstlineindent;
firstline.valueSize = sizeof(float);



CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[]={
    head,
    tail,
    firstline,

};
CTParagraphStyleRef style = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, 3);
```

Then the style is added to make an attributed string. I get the values from a theme stored in CoreData. That works well when I run the app on iPad, but on iPhone the code does not work.

I made a breakpoint to check what is the problem, and I found that the theme values are both right in the iPad and iPhone condition,but the value of  style ,which is a CTParagraphStyleRef, are all ZERO when running on iPhone.

Anyone has encounter same problem before? I just could not figure where is wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I just find the where the problem is...
In iPhone ,the sizeof(CGFloat) = 8 ,sizefo(float) = 4,
and in iPad , they are both 4.

But what still confused me is that since

```
typedef float CGFloat;
```

why their size are different.